# Is there a better way to display tags using PHP/MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli

Within my website, I make use of a tagging system. It works, however I noticed that it's extremely inefficient and needs to perform a separate SQL query for each tag in the event that I would like to display a list of tags.

[This is my tag table within the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRPKJ.png)

This is how tags are fetched and displayed:

```
$tags = json_decode(json_encode(explode(',', $row["tags"])));

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $fetchTags = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM tags WHERE id = ? AND type = 1");
    $fetchTags->bind_param("i", $tag);
    $fetchTags->execute();
    $fetchResult = $fetchTags->get_result();
    if($fetchResult->num_rows === 0) print('No rows');
    while($resultrow = $fetchResult->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?><span class="badge bg-primary me-2"><?php echo $resultrow["name"]; ?></span><?php
    }
    $fetchTags->close();
}
```

Note that the `$tags` would be equivalent to their tag ID(s) e.g. `1,2,3`. It may be fine for searching up 1 tag, but you can see the problem when you have 5-10 tags that need searching for.

I was thinking of having the tags being searched within 1 SQL query but the way MySQLi works and binding parameters is odd. I saw some people on here suggest using PDO but I'm not sure of how the implementation would work. I can use PDO instead if needed but ideally I would like to keep using MySQLi.

Comment: It would be much easier to do with PDO. If you are on PHP 8.1 already doing this with mysqli became a little easier too. If you can, I would highly advise using PDO. It will make your life much much easier. What you need to do, is fetch all the IDs outside the loop. In PDO I would use FETCH_KEY_PAIR, but in mysqli you don't have that. You can also use WHERE IN() to restrict the IDs to the ones you want.

Comment: If you continue using mysqli, try using `foreach` instead of `while`. It would make the code easier to read.

Comment: What's with `json_decode(json_encode`?

Comment: @Dharman I am on PHP 8.0 at the moment so I don't think I'll be able to take advantage of this considering the highest shared hosting supports is 8.0.

Also, I'm not sure why I had the json_decode/encode, I've removed that now since it makes no difference.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand. What can't you take advantage of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do it would be to run a single query with `WHERE IN` to match only the tags you need.

```
$tags = explode(',', $row["tags"]);
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($tags), '?'));
$fetchTags = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM tags WHERE id IN ('.$placeholders.') AND type = 1 ORDER BY id');
$fetchTags->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($tags)), ...$tags);
$fetchTags->execute();
$fetchResult = $fetchTags->get_result();
if($fetchResult->num_rows === 0) {
    print('No rows');
}
foreach($fetchResult as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

On PHP 8.1, you can avoid the `bind_param()` line and just pass the array in `execute()`.

```
$fetchTags->execute($tags);
```